# Do the inverses of individual divergent subsequences of a divergent sequence always converge?

Tags: divergent-series, analytic-continuation

> Do the inverses of individual divergent subsequences of a divergent sequence always converge?

I'm thinking the inverse of a a divergent sequence needn't necessarily converge because take say the sequence $\{1/2,2,1/4,4,1/8,8,\ldots\}$; its inverse contains a divergent subsequence.

But if we split it into its two separate subsequences, we can invert the divergent subsequence and we have a pair of convergent sequences.

When can and can't a sequence be partitioned into subsequences which can be inverted to converge?  And is this the essence of what's going on behind the scenes when we make an analytic continuation?

I imagine that by a process of repeated partitioning most divergent sequences (e.g. 95% of those found in a random sample taken from all divergent sequences mentioned on this site) can be treated like this and that potentially normal sequences such as the digits of $\pi$ which would perhaps cause the most difficulty.  But is this known to be the case?

Comment: By "series" I think you mean "sequence". By "trajectories" I think you mean "subsequences". By "inverse" I think you mean "termwise multiplicative inverse". There are good reasons for using the same words everyone else uses. Oh, and I have no idea what you mean by "most".

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson. Perhaps interestingly maths can be defined as nothing more than a language... with a vocabulary and correct and incorrect grammar.  Fluency is acquired.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ...I've defined "most".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ has a monotone subsequence. If that subsequence does not converge, it is unbounded. Thus its multiplicative inverse will converge to zero. If on the other hand it does converge, you are done.

By deleting that monotone subsequence, you have a new sequence which must have a monotone subsequence. Continuing indefinitely you can extract monotone subsequences all of which will converge or their inverses will.

By tacking on some initial elements to the subsequences, you can guarantee that the entire original sequence is covered in this way, so I would say your intuition is correct here.

Comment: Apologies for the terseness, I'm posting from a phone. I can provide more rigor later if you like.

Comment: np; I didn't;t think it was terse. So your assertion is that there is always a finite number of subsequences.

Comment: No not a finite number, almost certainly infinitely many.

Comment: A little more rigour would be greatly appreciated.  Please don't go to great lengths but I'm interested to understand better to what degree any divergent sequence can be broken down into subsequences which are either convergent or their inverse is.  In particular for every divergent sequence does there exist some composition of convergent subsequences which is equal to it. Clearly for the above example there is, but what about say some sequence which sums to $\pi$? My conjecture I guess is that $\pi$ is exactly the number whose composition cannot be completed.

Comment: There's no such thing as a sequence that sums to pi - do you mean a sequence that converges to pi?

Really, the construction I gave above should work for every real valued sequence, regardless of if it converges or not. It's a simple consequence of the "Monotone Subsequence Theorem".

Comment: Sorry I meant e.g. the digits of pi. ok thanks I'll look at the theorem.